# Libre Office Writer, Line Is Wrong Color

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I try to draw a straight line in Libre Office Writer.  (Version: 4.3.3.2)

I choose a color.  (Tried Black, Magenta, and Lime Green)

No matter what color I choose, I get Teal Blue.

What gives ?

Comment: It's the Henry Ford Edition of Libre Office: "You can have it any color you like, as long as it's black [or in this case teal blue]." :)

Comment: How did you choose the color? Using the "Drawing Object Properties" toolbar? Which color did you set? Line color or filling color? Which version of LibreOffice, which OS (just because i can't reproduce this with LO 4.2.7.2 on Linux Mint)

Comment: @Karan  good point.  I just included the version number

Comment: @tohuwawohu :  I don't know how I chose it.  There is a small drop down box on the tool bar which says "color" with another drop down box next to it.  In that box, there are dozens of colors.  Choosing such a color there has no effect.

Comment: Aha !!!!  Got it.  Barely touch the point of the cursor to the line, then right click on the line, and then click on "line" again in the resulting popup menu, then you can change the color.

Comment: Should I answer my own question ?

Comment: Well, it was a long time ago - but @User.1 you should have answered your own question, and thanks for the solution you provided in the comments; helped me solve the problem I was having right now...